# Background color to be the same height and width as the text or link

Tags: html, css

[image]

How to i reduce the height of the background color to be almost the same height as the link and i tried to use height on CSS but it didn't work

CSS

```
.login {

  color: #4CAF50;
  background-color: #a0ce4e;

}

.login a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #a0ce4e;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.login a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="login">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#">Login</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Link to the fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/y7g73b43/1/

Comment: Do you want to make your code like that image?

Comment: do you use external lib like bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Remove padding:

```
.login a {
  padding: 0px; /* or 1.. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those look like bootstrap classes, so I would say you likely need to remove padding and/or margins from navbar-nav.

You can do this by adding your own class to it and using that to add overriding styles. For example:

**CSS**:

```
.navbar-nav.navbar-nospace {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-nospace">
```